# Disabling SSL Certificate Validation for Active Directory server using spring-ldap 1.3.1

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I'm able to authenticate to Active Directory  if there is need to configure only one AD server. The solution is given as 
[Active Directory authentication through ssl as anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084534/active-directory-authentication-through-ssl-as-anonymous-user/17102928#17102928) by me.

Now I'm stuck when there is multiple ADs running behind a Load Balancer.

Since Load Balancer is in between, I will get the Host name only and the IP of AD will be replaced with the Host name behind the Load Balancer based on the availability. Therefore, I won't be able to know which Active Directory server will be used to process my request of authentication. So , I won't be able to generate the certificate in advance. Also, I can't get the IPs of ADs my client is using for balancing the load(for security reasons). so there is no point of generating **jssecacert**. All I need to do is to disable the certificate validation. I'm using ***LdapTemplate*** class(using spring-ldap 1.3.1) to authenticate the user. 
My spring Config looks like this...

```
<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />
     <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="yes" />
</bean>
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:636" />
</bean>
```

The authenticate method:

```
public boolean login(String username, String password) {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
            .../jssecacerts");

    boolean authenticate=false;

    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("xyz","xyz"));
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("xyz", xyz));

    authenticate = this.ldapTemplate.authenticate(base, filter.encode(), password); 
    return authenticate;

    }
```

Since we don't need to have certificate `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                .../jssecacerts");` 
will not be needed.

What changes I need to make to disable the certificate validation.

I'm pretty new in LDAP stuff. , Kindly help with appropriate answer.

Comment: This is not really LDAP specific here, this is rather related to TLS.

Comment: @fge Ya I agree when SSL comes in Place.

Comment: I don't see what OpenLDAP has to do with it either. Retagged to LDAP and SSL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, Thanks to Darren Hauge for providing a tricky solution that will not care about ssl certificate. Rewriting the solution here :

```
public static void trustSelfSignedSSL() {
    try {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All we need to create a utility class and put this method inside that. Call this method wherever you need.

Any comment on this solution is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: In the code above, you are using the default SSLContext, so you won't care about any certificates used on this application. Do you know if it is possible to skip certificate check only for this specific ldap certificate? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any way we can configure this in the startup param?

Comment: Side note, take care of wich import to use when pasting, do not use import from com.sun.*, but the one from `javax.net` and `java.security`