# Spring Security LDAPs authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

i need help in Spring Security authentication with Ldap.
I try lot of things found online but i'm going crazy on this.
Basiclly i need to pass username and password to ldaps server

this is my pom.xml for security

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and this is my SecurityConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .permitAll().and().logout();
    }
    
    @Bean
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        return new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("@DOMAIN.it", "ldaps://NAME.DOMAIN.it:636/");
    }

}
```

whrn i try to login i recive this errors

```
mw.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter: An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Connection to LDAP server failed.
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.badLdapConnection(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:312) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:171) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:79) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_341]
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: NAME.DOMAIN.it:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: NAME.DOMAIN.it:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed]
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:108) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:224) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:167) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: NAME.DOMAIN.it:636
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider$ContextFactory.createContext(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:416) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:217) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Ldaps server work fine because in a simple java application i can check if user is authenticated or not by simple boolean function.

Comment: As you are using `ldaps` please add certificate to java keystore. certificate must be with `NAME.DOMAIN.it` name.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar any way to skip the certificate import into java keystore?

Comment: well, either turn off SSL and just use ldap:, Or SSL debug:   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: @DhavalGajjar adding certificate into java keystore not work for me

Comment: @DougGrove this helped me, now i can get more specific error in console, now i get `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: The error shows that you have not added certificate to keystore. Also make sure your CA certificate is added in cacert. All certificate chain must be validated through keystore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that the certificate wasn't import correctly.
Thanks to importcert i recovered the correct certificate and now i can authenticate an user.
This helped for me: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/07/ldap-authentication-active-directory-authentication-java-spring-security-example.html#axzz7zyBjZQeo

**EDIT** also this help beause certificate change after a few months. In this case certificate is ever trusted. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17205582/21640328